# IllegalStateException Compiling Clojure-Contrib

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

I am trying to compile my own version of clojure-contrib with Maven I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't dynamically bind non-dynamic var: clojure.contrib.pprint/*format-str*, compiling:(dispatch.clj:90)
```

I am also using the following command to compile it:

```
mvn package -Dclojure.jar=/usr/local/share/jars/clojure.jar
```

clojure.jar is link to the actual jar (that is on the same directory) because I am using a version that I compiled from the Git repository.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance for your comments! =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

clojure-contrib, the single monolithic build, is deprecated after Clojure 1.2.0 and is not actively maintained.  It doesn't build on the latest Clojure 1.3.0-alpha* releases.

New contrib libraries, one per Github repository, are being created under http://github.com/clojure

See http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Clojure+Contrib and its sub-pages for more information.