# How to build clojure_contrib with Clojure v 1.6?

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

I've downloaded the current stable version of Clojure on my Macbook, which is 1.6.

However, I only find the way to build `clojure_contrib` with clojure 1.3 or older.

So how can I build it with clojure v1.6 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IllegalStateException Compiling Clojure-Contrib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877331/illegalstateexception-compiling-clojure-contrib)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know, I'm giving answer to another question, but still.

You don't need to build clojure-contrib. If it's some book/tutorial you are reading - grab clojure-1.3. If you are porting old project to clojure-1.6 - switch it to new modular clojure-contrib (http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go).